# Are there any Whiskey better for cocktails?

Tags: whiskey, cocktails

I would like to know what whiskey is better with cocktails.

I've bough the Jack Daniels, but I feel that the taste of the cocktail is off since the flavors of the Jack Daniels is stronger than others. I might be wrong but I really do taste the Jack Daniels in any cocktails involving whiskey.

I wonder then what whiskey is mostly used for cocktails and what whiskey is mostly used for shots or straight consumption.

If any of my sayings are wrong or badly expressed just let me know.

Comment: I think it's largely a matter of getting the ingredients to pair well together.  There probably isn't a single best rye for a Manhattan for example, but there are great pairs of rye and vermouth.  Getting both of them right makes a difference.  The same is almost certainly true of most cocktails.

Comment: In cocktails the primary character comes from the mix and any add-ins, with the whisky being secondary. So I'd usually just get the style right, and go cheap, but not too cheap. Unless you have money to burn.

Comment: @Ola - please stop editing whisky to whiskey. Both words are correct spelling - whisky for Scotch, Whiskey for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I mix Cocktails with Irish Whiskeys into cocktails because of their smooth taste and generally, because they match so well with other alcohols. So if you don't like that the Jack is getting so much attention in your cocktail, you can switch to something other than a rich Bourbon.

If you want a recommendation, you can try mixing Jameson with Ginger Ale as Longdrink.

Or if you want to mix a cocktail, the Long Island Icetea is a way to see if your choice of Whiskey mixes well with other spirits. For this cocktail you can even choose a cheaper Whiskey, be it Bourbon like Jim Beam or Tullamore Dew as for an Irish one because it is more difficult to aknowledge the different spirits in the mixture.

And after all, you shouldn't mix expensive Whiskey in a cocktail, that's just not right.

Comment: Thanks for the info I'll check it out and try some things with that

Answer (score 3):

Jack Daniels is not a whisky! It is a Tennessee Whiskey!

That is very different to the Scotch whisky usually recommended in whisky cocktails, which require more of a bitter/tart edge than the sweetness of Jack Daniels.

For any whisky cocktail I personally would use a decent single malt Scotch whisky to get the best taste for me, but everyone's palate is different. I only use Jack Daniels in sweet cocktails, or with cola.

Answer (score 0):

You should really think about all of the different Scotch, Whiskey, and Bourbon selections as spices in a recipe. Cinnamon and sugar go great on doughnuts but not so much with spinach salads.

Sure, some people will ***LOSE THEIR MINDS*** if you were to put "a rare sipping ::insert spirit of choice::" into a coke... But... if that is what you want to do. You do it and enjoy it fully.

Start looking at [Flavor Profiles](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5xoOPnezYAhXvUN8KHerXCLIQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.revolutionanalytics.com%2F2014%2F01%2Fwhere-the-whisky-flavor-profile-data-came-from.html&psig=AOvVaw1Bx4WBjzdyRQuvoOFgZztl&ust=1516733064912129) and then learn what pairs well with the types of drinks you want to mix into them. There are probably a lot of mixology-style techniques for drink prep (think [Flaming Dr Pepper shot](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihw-CynezYAhXKhOAKHaPsDu0QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.liquor.com%2Frecipes%2Fflaming-dr-pepper-shot%2F&usg=AOvVaw3t7dD4zGhCRM0H1nxhTQjz)) that I am unaware of.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I'll give it a read and try some